# How can I create a modal dialog in Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, modal-dialog, add-in

I have to develop an Outlook Compose Add-in and I try to open a modal dialog to enter some information in that. But I haven't found any concerned API.

So is there any way to create a modal dialog in Outlook Add-in?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Web based addin? There is no way.